# Subclassing UITableViewController to be subclassed again in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, controller, subclass

I'm wanting to make a subclass of UITableViewController that has some specific functions in it. That way when I make a TableViewController in the storyboard I can just subclass this new class I made.

But when I try to replace `UITableViewController` with my new class, I get errors about not having `viewDidLoad()` function or any of the other lifecycle functions.

Here is my subclass of `UITableViewController`:

```
class TutorialTVC: UITableViewController {

var tutorialTab: TutorialTab?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.tutorialTab?.dropDownTab()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.tutorialTab?.pullUpTab(0.2)
}

func createTutorialTab(segueNameOnOpen: String) {
    self.tutorialTab = TutorialTab(sourceVC: self, putTabBelowView: nil, segueNameOnOpen: segueNameOnOpen)
}

}
```

As you can see, I tried adding in the `override` for `viewDidLoad()`, but even then is states this:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass.

I thought that when you subclass something, all of it's functions are brought in as well... Or is there additional code I need to add to make this happen. I'm pretty new to subclassing like this.

Comment: This works for me in a playground. Try to clean your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you didn't import `UIKit` in this file. However you can create your class as subClass of `UITableViewController` right from the interface as below,

[image]

This will handle `import` of `UIKit`. Also it will add all the essential methods to start with `TableViewController`.